# Can any amp-hour capacity battery be used in any Kobalt 80V cordless electric mower, or is each Kobalt 80V mower amp-hour specific?

Tags: powertools, battery

I have a 2.5Ah 80V battery from Kobalt for a weedwacker and am looking to get a mower. I see some good used Kobalt 80V mowers but it's not always clear if it was originally sold with a 2.5Ah battery, or a 4Ah battery or what. Are these mowers fit to specific capacity batteries?

On Lowe's website there are Kobalt 80V mowers sold with different amp-hour batteries:

- [Here's one that takes a 2.5Ah battery](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-80-volt-Brushless-Lithium-Ion-21-in-Self-Propelled-Cordless-Electric-Lawn-Mower-Batteries-Included/1000478561) ($600)
- [Same thing sold with 4Ah battery](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-80-volt-Max-Brushless-Lithium-Ion-Self-propelled-21-in-Cordless-Electric-Lawn-Mower/1001763308) ($750)
- [Same thing sold with 5Ah battery](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-80-volt-Max-Brushless-Lithium-Ion-Push-21-in-Cordless-Electric-Lawn-Mower/1000698036) ($500)

The 4Ah and 5Ah 80V battery looks the same as my 2.5Ah 80V battery but I'm not sure if that capacity difference would matter somehow. The difference in price for those pages further confuses matters to me.

Comment: The amp-hour rating of a battery is not really a factor in compatibility, so long as it's not vastly different from the original battery.  If one battery's amp-hour rating is within a factor of 2 of the alternative battery then there should be no problem (other than operating duration), provided the voltages are (nearly) identical.

Comment: @HotLicks that's what I thought. I second guessed it seeing how different prices were on the otherwise-same mowers.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that, while the amp-hour ratings are not especially important, the peak current ratings are.  Whichever battery you use must have a peak current rating sufficiently large to supply the motor without a major dip in voltage.  Unfortunately, you may need an Ouija board to figure out the motor's peak current draw.

Comment: Car battery $100, DC-DC converter (80 V output) $30 = 20 Amp hours

Comment: @Ruskes - more like 15Ah, and that's only if you pretend the converter is 100% efficient and you're ok with only getting a single use out of it due to over-discharging your car battery (since car batteries are not deep cycle), and your converter can hand the motor starting current as easily as a battery can, and etc....

Comment: I have more than a dozen DeWALT 20v batteries ranging from 2 to 8Ah. They will all work in _any_ of my DeWALT tools. I get more run time from the higher Ah rated batteries. I'm pretty sure it'll be the same for Kobalt brand tools and, actually for `<insert brand name here>` tools.

Comment: @FreeMan Hand tools are a different ballgame compared to a lawnmower. My toolset is Ridgid and most tools feel about the same regardless of Ah rating. The one handtool where I can notice a difference is in their [Jobsite Blower](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-18V-Lithium-Ion-Cordless-Compact-Jobsite-Blower-with-Inflator-Deflator-Nozzle-R86043B/314241140). The engine revs audibly higher with a 4 Ah as opposed to the 2 Ah; the 9 Ah sounds the same as the 4 Ah. Read https://www.protoolreviews.com/battery-amp-hours-affect-power/ for more info.

Comment: TBF, @MonkeyZeus, the 8Ah battery is their "XR" or "Plus" (or something) and came with the 7-1/4" circular saw. The saw will run on any of the smaller batteries, but not nearly as well. Even no-load, it doesn't sound like it spins up as quickly. Other tools do sound like the run a little faster with that 8Ah battery, but it's heavy enough I really don't use it except for cutting (circular, jig, sometimes grinder).

Comment: @FreeMan Right, that's what I'm saying. The battery will fit and deliver the correct voltage but that's not the whole story =). Anecdote: I hooked up my kids' 12V Powerwheels to my Ridgid batteries and notice no difference in speed when one kid has a 2 Ah and the other has a 4 Ah; they both weigh almost exactly the same.

Comment: @FreeMan Speaking of circular saws, my 9 Ah battery won't fit into mine due to clearance issues, heh.

Comment: @FreeMan your comment about compatibility is really an answer to my question. Revisiting the Lowe's pages I also learned all 80V batteries are interchangeable by design (stated in the second video on the 5Ah mower page)

Comment: Tim "The Tool Man" @MonkeyZeus, you need to up the amperage on those Powerwheels to the point where the kids need a license to drive 'em! :D

Comment: @cr0 that makes perfect sense. It wouldn't make much sense to have multiple, incompatible batteries marketed with the same voltage line. People would be returning the wrong battery all the time. DeWALT has their 12v and 20v lines, and I don't think the batteries will interchange (though some/all chargers will charge both, I think). But 20v (type A) and 20v (type B) would simply be a mess...

Comment: @FreeMan I tried hooking up two in series to get 36v but it immediately smoked the motor. The 9 Ah battery performs the same as the 2 Ah, which is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampere-hour rating for a battery is a rough approximation of run time, also approximately equivalent to fuel capacity. I was temporarily confused by the disparity in prices, but then noted that the two more expensive units provide two batteries and operate on two batteries, while the lowest price one uses a single battery.

This means the $600 unit has 5 Ah capacity, the $750 unit has 8 Ah capacity. The lowest price one appears to be a better deal in that it's a 5 Ah battery priced one hundred dollars less than the two battery version.